# Conclude $r$ from a contradiction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am having a problem with figuring out why I'm doing what I am doing in line 8-11 in this proof. I only did it this way because I have seen it done in others proofs but i do not understand why you can do it that way.

I used an online tool called BoxProver to check the correction of my proof:

[image]

The way I see it from line 7 we say that -q. Then we make another assumption and say q. Of course this makes a contradiction but i don't see how we can conclude r from this. And I don't see how we can conclude q->r since we obviously said that q was not true.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Note that your given $q \vee \neg q$ is a disjunction.
Particularly, all your proof's strategy is based on getting rid of it through disjunction elimination:

- **$\vee$ Elim**: $ \qquad \dfrac{\Gamma, \alpha \vdash  \gamma \qquad \Gamma, \beta \vdash \gamma \qquad \Gamma \vdash \alpha \lor \gamma}{\Gamma \vdash \beta}$

During 8-11 you are simply using the [*ex falso*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) or explosion principle

- **EP**: $  \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\alpha , \neg\alpha}{\beta}$

in order to obtain $(q \rightarrow r)$ fro the assumption that $\neg q$ holds.

Comment: But how can we say that r is true just because -q holds? I don't get it

Comment: @VictorVH Not only $\neg q$, but because both $\neg q$ and $q$ hold, that is, a contradiction. Roughly, the principle of explosion states that from a contradiction we may derive anything we want. I suggest you to have a look at the Wikipedia link I attached above.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @VictorVH You're welcome :)